# Convert from html entity number to accented char

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

in this rss feed ( http://nightly.gamempire.it/rss ) you can visualize some html entity numbers (like `&#224;` that will be converted to `à` if the encoding is utf-8).

However, this rss show `&#224;`: how can I convert it to `à`?
Is there a php function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
html_entity_decode('&#224;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepad.org/yOSbDtNE)